# Performance tuning of a Hibernate+Spring+MySQL project operation that stores images uploaded by user

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring, blob

I am working on a web project that is **Spring+Hibernate+MySQL** based. I am stuck at a point where I have to store images uploaded by a user into the database. Although I have written some code that works well for now, but I believe that things will mess up when the project would go live.

Here's my domain class that carries the image bytes:

```
@Entity
public class Picture implements java.io.Serializable{
    long id;
    byte[] data;
    ... // getters and setters
}
```

And here's my controller that saves the file on submit:

```
public class PictureUploadFormController extends AbstractBaseFormController{
    ...
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception{
         MutlipartFile file; 
         // getting MultipartFile from the command object
         ...
         // beginning hibernate transaction
         ...
         Picture p=new Picture();
         p.setData(file.getBytes());
         pictureDAO.makePersistent(p); // this method simply calls getSession().saveOrUpdate(p)

         // committing hiernate transaction
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Obviously a bad piece of code. Is there anyway I could use **InputStream** or **Blob** to save the data, instead of first loading all the bytes from the user into the memory and then pushing them into the database?

I did some research on hibernate's support for Blob, and found this in Hibernate In Action book:

> java.sql.Blob and java.sql.Clob are
>   the most efficient way to handle large
>   objects in Java. Unfortunately, an
>   instance of Blob or Clob is only
>   useable until the JDBC transaction
>   completes. **So if your persistent class
>   defines a property of java.sql.Clob or
>   java.sql.Blob (not a good idea
>   anyway), you’ll be restricted in how
>   instances of the class may be used.** In
>   particular, you won’t be able to use
>   instances of that class as detached
>   objects. Furthermore, many JDBC
>   drivers don’t feature working support
>   for java.sql.Blob and java.sql.Clob.
>   Therefore, it makes more sense to map
>   large objects using the binary or text
>   mapping type, assuming retrieval of
>   the entire large object into memory
>   isn’t a performance killer.
>
> Note you
>   can find up-to-date design patterns
>   and tips for large object usage on the
>   Hibernate website, with tricks for
>   particular platforms.

Now *apparently* the Blob cannot be used, as it is **not a good idea anyway**, what else could be used to improve the performance? I couldn't find any **up-to-date design pattern** or any useful information on Hibernate website. So any help/recommendations from stackoverflowers will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revised edition of the book ([Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/)) says:

> Table 5.3 lists Hibernate types for handling binary data and large values. Note that
>   only `binary` is supported as the type of an identifier property.

```
Mapping type   Java type   Standard SQL built-in type
binary         byte[]               VARBINARY
text           java.lang.String     CLOB
clob           java.sql.Clob        CLOB
blob           java.sql.Blob        BLOB
serializable   Any Java class that  VARBINARY
               implements
               java.io.Serializable
```

> If a property in your persistent Java class is of type `byte[]`, Hibernate can map
>   it to a `VARBINARY` column with the binary mapping type. (Note that the real SQL type depends on the dialect; for example, in PostgreSQL, the SQL type is BYTEA,
>   and in Oracle it’s RAW.) If a property in your persistent Java class is of type
>   java.lang.String, Hibernate can map it to an SQL CLOB column, with the text
>   mapping type.
>
> Note that in both cases, Hibernate initializes the property value right away,
>   when the entity instance that holds the property variable is loaded. This is inconvenient
>   when you have to deal with potentially large values.
>
> One solution is lazy loading through interception of field access, on demand.
>   However, this approach requires bytecode instrumentation of your persistent
>   classes for the injection of extra code. We’ll discuss lazy loading through bytecode
>   instrumentation and interception in chapter 13, section 13.1.6, “Lazy loading
>   with interception.”
>
> A second solution is a different kind of property in your Java class. JDBC supports
>   locator objects (LOBs) directly.1 If your Java property is of type
>   java.sql.Clob or java.sql.Blob, you can map it with the clob or blob mapping
>   type to get lazy loading of large values without bytecode instrumentation. When
>   the owner of the property is loaded, the property value is a locator object—effectively,
>   a pointer to the real value that isn’t yet materialized. Once you access the
>   property, the value is materialized. This on-demand loading works only as long as
>   the database transaction is open, so you need to access any property of such a type
>   when the owning entity instance is in a persistent and transactional state, not in
>   detached state. Your domain model is now also bound to JDBC, because the
>   import of the java.sql package is required. Although domain model classes are
>   executable in isolated unit tests, you can’t access LOB properties without a database
>   connection.

Hope this helps.